# Android APK permission analyzer

Tags: android, user-permissions

I'm trying to understand whether Google does indeed provide an APK permission analyzer? I did find this: http://code.google.com/p/apk-permission-analyzer/ If not, does Google (outside of Bouncer) check the APK permissions for "relevance"? Lots of apps (not naming here) have access to non-relevant permissions i.e. contacts and calendar. Some say apps require these permissions to work. I for one don't believe this is true for a lot of apps I've reviewed.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to understand whether Google does indeed provide an APK permission analyzer?

If you are referring to something along the lines of the linked-to project, no.

> If not, does Google (outside of Bouncer) check the APK permissions for "relevance"?

Not as far as we are aware.

Comment: Thanks. I believe also, Bouncer is not checking APK permissions either.